# API not accepting List of objects as a parameter .Net Core webAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi

I am working on an API that accepts a list of Objects as a parameter.
This is the Api I am working with:

```
[HttpPost("PharmacySupply")]
        public async Task<List<PharmacyMedicineSupply>> GetPharmacySupply(List<MedicineDemand> medDemand)
        {
            SupplyRepo sr = new SupplyRepo();
            return await sr.GetPharmacySupply(medDemand);
        }
```

This is my model :

```
public class MedicineDemand
    {
        public string Medicine { get; set; }
        public int DemandCount { get; set; }
    }
```

I am passing this in swagger as parameter:

```
[
{Dolo,7},
{Cholecalciferol,9},
{Orthoherb,5},
{Gaviscon,2},
{Hilact,3}
{Cyclopam,1}
]
```

but the parameter is empty . It is showing a count of 0 while debugging.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `[FromBody]` if you are testing using postman. ([See [FromBody] documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0))

```cs
 public async Task<List<PharmacyMedicineSupply>> GetPharmacySupply([FromBody] List<MedicineDemand> medDemand)
```

for test in postman you have to use

```json
[
   { "Medicine": "Dolo", "DemandCount" : 7},
   { "Medicine": "Cholecalciferol", "DemandCount" : 9},
   ...
]
```

and if maybe you try for testing in swagger with this

```json
[
   { "Dolo" , 7 },
   { "Cholecalciferol" , 9 },
   ...
]
```

Comment: @sapter -- [you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689524/api-to-accept-list-of-object-as-a-parameter-netcore) 6 hours ago and I told you in comments to put `[FromBody]` in the parameters. Please don't ask the same question multiple times.